# Compare two csv and merge them

Tags: python, angularjs, csv, pandas

I need to use Python and Angular JS to send a CSV file from python to web page and display it accordingly.

I've got 2 CSV files with fields as

CSV1

```
Country code,Telecom,Latency

919618, India Private Mobile,0.008800

919619, India Private Mobile,0.008800

919620, India Private Mobile,0.008800
```

CSV2

```
Country code,Telecom,Latency

919802, India Private Mobile,0.008400

919803, India Private Mobile,0.008400

919620, India Private Mobile,0.008400
```

The web page should display as

```
Country code,Telecom,Latency

919618, India Private Mobile,0.008800

919619, India Private Mobile,0.008800

919802, India Private Mobile,0.008400

919803, India Private Mobile,0.008400

919620,India Private Mobile,0.008400,0.008800
```

(The last line contain two values cause the CSV file contains 919620 commons in both)

So now I'm new to Angular JS and Flask, 
just guide me how to start?

started with this

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


dfa = pd.read_csv('rate4.csv', names=['Country Code', 'SP', 'Rate']);
dfb = pd.read_csv('rate3.csv', names=['Country Code', 'SP', 'Rate']);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merging 2 csv files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16265831/merging-2-csv-files)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use for output `DataFrame` use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) and [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by columns `Country code` and `Telecom` with `join` column `Latency`:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2]) \
       .groupby(['Country code','Telecom'])['Latency'] \
       .apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.astype(str))) \
       .reset_index()
print (df)
   Country code               Telecom        Latency
0        919618  India Private Mobile         0.0088
1        919619  India Private Mobile         0.0088
2        919620  India Private Mobile  0.0088,0.0084
3        919802  India Private Mobile         0.0084
4        919803  India Private Mobile         0.0084
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Yash Kumar Atri/PycharmProjects/untitled/test/prettyprint.py", line 12, in <module>
    df = pd.concat([dfa, dfb]).groupby(['Country Code','Telecom'])['Latency'].join(lambda x: ','.join(x.astype(str)))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py", line 551, in __getattr__
    (type(self).__name__, attr))
AttributeError: 'SeriesGroupBy' object has no attribute 'join'

Comment: hey can you suggest me something for displaying whole data at once cause it display 28              233            GHANA FIXED  0.0088
29              234          NIGERIA FIXED  0.0088
...             ...                    ...     ...
20431      91612794            India Fixed  0.0084
20432      91674791            India Fixed  0.0084      cause it display triple dots in between

Comment: Unfortunately I have no idea, never do something in `Flask`. Maybe help some another post like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22180993/2901002) or  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39403732/2901002)